# OneHotEncoder returns unexpected result

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[['Team A', 'Team B', 5000]
['Team C', 'Team D', 4000]]
```

Using this OneHotEncoder to transform the teamnames

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ct = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[(
        'encoder',
        OneHotEncoder(),
        [0, 1]
    )],
    remainder='passthrough'
)

X = np.array(
    ct.fit_transform(X)
)
```

What I would expect is X to be something like:

```
[[1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 5000]
[0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 4000]]
```

However when I print it looks more like this:

```
(0, 12) 1.0
(0, 17) 1.0
(0, 28) 5000.0
(1, 5)  1.0
(1, 25) 1.0
(1, 28) 4000.0
```

What am I missing in this case? If I include more columns in the X variable to begin with I get the expected result:

```
[['Team A' 'Team B' 2 0 1 0.0 0.0 0 1 2 0.0 1.0 5000]
 ['Team C' 'Team D' 2 3 0 nan nan 2 1 1 nan nan 4000]]
```

I do not understand what the differens is in these cases? Why do I get different results on the same columns when only other columns has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reproduce the issue with the sample data you have posted; for

```
[['Team A', 'Team B', 5000]
['Team C', 'Team D', 4000]]
```

I get `X` as

```
array([[1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 5000],
       [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4000]], dtype=object)
```

Nevertheless, most probably the issue is with the default setting `sparse=True` of the OneHoteEncoder (see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.transform)) - the representation you end up getting looks like a sparse one. If you don't want it like that, change the `OneHotEncoder()` definition in your `ColumnTransformer` to `OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)` (probably the reason I cannot reproduce it is that the sample dataset is way too small, and the sparse representation simply does not kick in in such cases).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was the sparse that was causing the issue, had no idea what a sparse matrix was before, now I know, thanks again! :) My real dataset is a few thousands lines so that mig be why.

Comment: For the record, the `OneHotEncoder` will produce a sparse array no matter the size of the data, with the default value `sparse=True`.  But the `ColumnTransformer` will condense it depending on the size and sparsity of the rest of its output, depending on the value of `sparse_threshold`.

Comment: @BenReiniger thanks, good to know you've got my back ;)